# Bind() to a dynamically embedded souncloud widget

Tags: javascript, api, widget, soundcloud, oembed

I am using the following code to embed a soundcloud widget:

```
SC.oEmbed(soundcloud_url, {color: "3C9FCE"},  document.getElementById('container_id'));
```

How do I bind a SC.Widget.Events.Ready to it? I don't see any way to set the id or class of the embed iframe so that I can select it. Nor do I know when it has been loaded so that I can bind it, such as the following dysfunctional code:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('container_id').getElementsByTag("iframe")[0];
frame.bind(SC.Widget.Events.Ready, listnerFucnt());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the reason you are using SoundCloud JavaScript SDK is to be able 
to `SC.oembed` to get embed HTML when having only SoundCloud permalink, 
then you probably shouldn't. You can interact with either `/resolve` 
or `/oembed` endpoints instead.

The difference is that `/oembed` endpoint doesn't require `client_id` 
to be specified in request, so let's start with this approach first.

#### Option 1

I'll use jQuery, but the idea should be clear:

```
var SOUNDCLOUD_URL = 'http://soundcloud.com/georgconrad/shostakovich2',
    WIDGET_OPTIONS = '&color=3C9FCE&liking=false';

jQuery
  .getJSON( 
    'http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?url=' + SOUNDCLOUD_URL + WIDGET_OPTIONS 
  )
  .done( function ( data ) {
    var widget;
    $('body').html( data.html );
    widget = SC.Widget($('body').find('iframe')[0]);
    widget.bind('ready', function () {
      alert('widget ready');
    });
  });
```

This code live and commented – http://jsbin.com/ilesum/2/edit

#### Option 2

The other thing you could do is to use `/resolve` endpoint, but you have to specify `client_id` in order to interact with it, plus you will need to construct Widget iframe HTML yourself (which isn't too bad though):

```
var SOUNDCLOUD_URL = 'http://soundcloud.com/georgconrad/shostakovich2',
    CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    TEMPLATE = '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" ' +
               'frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url={url}{options}" '+ 
               'class="sc-widget"></iframe>';

$.getJSON(
  'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + SOUNDCLOUD_URL + 
  '&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID
).done(function ( soundData ) {
  // I am using String.prototype.supplant from Crockford
  // (if you follow example code link you'll see what I mean)
  $('body').html(TEMPLATE.supplant({
    url: soundData.uri,
    options: '&color=3C9FCE'
  }));
  widget = SC.Widget($('body').find('iframe')[0]);
  widget.bind('ready', function () {
    alert('widget ready');
  });
});
```

And example live as well http://jsbin.com/oqebuk/2/edit

Please note you can disable **HTML** or **Output** panes on JSBin, so it's easier to read the example JavaScript code.

Comment: Perfect! The second option you provided is exactly what I was looking for.