# Retrieve Soundcloud search results and embed results

Tags: php, soundcloud

With Soundcloud, I've been looking at the API, but I'm not quite sure of the best way to do what I want.

I'm building a site which I'll use to host a number of sound files on Soundcloud. I'd like to be able to let people search for sounds (they'll be sermon mp3 files for a church website) and then list the results on our site, together with the embedded player.

What would be the best approach to use to display a player for each of the returned search results? Obviously, speed is a concern for us - so would like to approach this the best way.

Just a general approach would be fine - and if there is an example line of code or two, that would be awesome. I'm using PHP.

Thanks for any help,

Toby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach could be the following:

1. Get search query from user
2. Issue a request to http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=YOUR_QUERY&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID<sup>*</sup>
3. Get JSON that will contain an array of tracks that you can iterate on and access properties, like sound id and parse it, store this in variable (maybe `tracks`)
4. Create a variable, an empty string (maybe `html`)
5. Iterate over `tracks` list, take a template for HTML5 widget<sup>*</sup> and replace key for sound `id` with sound id of current track (`currentTrack.id`) on each iteration, add the processed template into `html`)
6. Print `html` out

<sup>*</sup>Notes:

- Template for HTML5 widget as a string (replace `{trackId}` with current sound id while iterating, and `{widgetParams}` with something like `&color=ff6600&auto_play=false` of course matching the desired params for your own embed) (more on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14900820/236135)):

  ```
  <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F{trackId}{widgetParams}"></iframe>
  ```
- When I say process template, I mean that you need to replace “keys” with some other strings, you can do that easily in different languages, either `replace` method of String type, or google “variable interpolation”.
- The base API URL can be different – you can use `q=QUERY` with different endpoints such as

  - `/users/USER_ID/tracks.json`
  - `/groups/GROUP_ID/tracks.json`

  Or you can combine filters like tags `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=YOUR_QUERY&tags=sermon&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

For API responses and options you have refer to [SoundCloud API Reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference)

Comment: Absolutely perfect - thanks heaps for this! All I needed to know.

Comment: @gryzzly: Can i use soundcloud API to send request from my website (based on user input) and get soundcloud search results for that request and play on my website ?

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din yes, you can